# azure storage conneciton string inside android apps security

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am accessing azure storage account upload and download from android app using connection string hardcoded in my apps's code, what all alternatives I have to access instead of just using connection string.

Answer (score 1):

> what all alternatives I have to access instead of just using
>   connection string.

Essentially you have two alternatives:

1. **Use Shared Access Signature (SAS)**: You can have your Android App make a request to your web server and request a SAS URL and then you use that SAS URL in your application to interact with storage.
2. **Use Azure AD Based Authentication**: You could secure your application using Azure AD based authentication/authorization and then use the access token received from Azure AD to interact with storage.

You can learn more about these here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage.

**UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCES YOU SHOULD EMBED YOUR CONNECTION STRING INSIDE YOUR APPLICATION.**